# How to make nested list with merged elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

Let's say I have a list:

```
l = ['1 bd', '1 ba', '565 sqft', '- Apartment for rent', '2 bds', '1 ba', '1,200 sqft', '- Apartment for rent', 'None', '2 bds', '1 ba', '-- sqft', '- Apartment for rent', '1 bd', '1 ba', '382 sqft', '- Apartment for rent', 'None', '1 bd', '1 ba', '615 sqft', '- Apartment for rent', '1 bd', '1 ba', '478 sqft', '- Apartment for rent', '1 bd', '1 ba', '529 sqft', '- Apartment for rent']
```

How can I make a nested list so that different lists inside that one can consist of a different number of merged elements?

Expected output:

```
l = [['1 bd, 1 ba, 565 sqft, - Apartment for rent'], ['2 bds, 1 ba, 1,200 sqft, - Apartment for rent'], ['None'], ['2 bds, 1 ba, -- sqft, - Apartment for rent'], ['1 bd, 1 ba, 382 sqft, - Apartment for rent'], ['None'], ['1 bd, 1 ba, 615 sqft, - Apartment for rent'], ['1 bd, 1 ba, 478 sqft, - Apartment for rent'], ['1 bd, 1 ba, 529 sqft, - Apartment for rent']]
```

The items in the lists do not have to look exactly like the above(commas or hyphens). My goal is to put them together in a meaningful way.

Comment: How is the original list created? Why don't you just create a more useful data structure to begin with such as a list of class objects?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am scrapping an apartment rental site with the help of BeautifulSoup. The problem is in the markup so that this is the only way to get that data for further processing.

Comment: @julsk0 hey check my answer, is it helpful?

Comment: @julsk0 I suggest creating an `Apartment` class with fields like `bedrooms`, `sqft`, etc. Then as you scrape the data from the webpage with beautifulsoup, create instances of these classes directly. Lists are most useful for sequences of similar data, such as a list of `Apartment` objects. They are much less useful for a collection of related data that each has a different meaning. There are more meaningful ways to organize your data than just lists of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `itertools` `accumulate()` and `groupby()`. For example:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, groupby

key = ['for rent' in e or e == 'None' for e in l]
[', '.join([v for k, v in g]) for _, g in groupby(zip(accumulate([0] + key), l), key=lambda gv: gv[0])]
```

Gives:

```py
['1 bd, 1 ba, 565 sqft, - Apartment for rent',
 '2 bds, 1 ba, 1,200 sqft, - Apartment for rent',
 'None',
 '2 bds, 1 ba, -- sqft, - Apartment for rent',
 '1 bd, 1 ba, 382 sqft, - Apartment for rent',
 'None',
 '1 bd, 1 ba, 615 sqft, - Apartment for rent',
 '1 bd, 1 ba, 478 sqft, - Apartment for rent',
 '1 bd, 1 ba, 529 sqft, - Apartment for rent']
```

**Explanation**:

We make a `key` that detects an "end of one listing": either `'for rent'` is in the string, or the string is `'None'` (of course, adjust ad lib).

Accumulate then makes groups (0 for the first listing, 1 for the second, etc.)

Groupby splits the stream into groups. Then it is simply a matter of joining the right bits.

Comment: Instead of answering questions that don't demonstrate any effort on OP's part, I'd suggest a better strategy is to add a comment pointing them in the right direction, and flag to close. Giving OP the code they are asking for doesn't help them because they won't learn, and it doesn't help the community because it encourages more basic questions without research/coding effort.

Comment: The OP provided a MRE, which is more than a substantial proportion of questions on SO. Plus, it was a fun opportunity to point out the sometimes overlooked power of some of `itertools` functions...

Comment: Providing the input list and expected output does _not_ count as a [mre] when it doesn't include any code to process this list. A MRE is supposed to be a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates a problem they found _in their code_

Comment: @PierreD, thank you for explanation!!!! I made a nested list with simple for loop after this.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'm sorry if I made you angry, but not all people know what you know. I was puzzled by this problem, I tried to figure it out on my own, but I do not have much experience to understand which way I should move. This doesn't mean I just copy-paste the solution, now I know what I should learn to handle similar by myself the next time.

Comment: @julsk0 You didn't make me angry. When I was first learning programming, I found it much more helpful to make mistakes and understand what I was doing wrong than to look online for a readymade answer. Trust me, it's much better this way. Nobody writes perfect code on their first try, even after decades of experience. 
Learning how to [find and fix your mistakes](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is just as important as knowing how to write the code in the first place. Try it yourself, and if you have _specific_ questions about your attempt, we're here to help :)

Comment: @julsk0 moreover, since you were stuck somewhere, I'm sure you'd find it more helpful to ask _"where do I go from here"_ instead of _"how do I do this"_. In this case, the answer that Pierre gave uses some higher-level concepts in Python and you really need to get a grasp of the basics, such as loops before you use fancy constructs like `groupby()` and `accumulate()`, and this answer won't really help you there.